# Material Angular Text box with shadow

Tags: angular, input, angular-material

I am designing a form and i would like the input box like the picture below in angular material matInput. How to achieve this?

Here is a screenshot of how i want the input box to be displayed:

[image]

Comment: I guess you'll have to override all material styles. But I don't know why you would use angular material and then completely get rid of material design, that sounds a little bit counter-productive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By shadow I guess you mean the filled appearance of a material text field. You get this look by adding `appearance="fill"` to your `mat-form-field`.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Fill form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
</mat-form-field>
```

[Form field appearance variants](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-appearance-variants)

Comment: Thanks Fridoo. This is what I was expecting and works fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want more control, add this to style sheet

```
.mat-form-field-flex{
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

you can find the css class for each part of the component in the dev console.